# PhoneGap app for Symbian | "Application closed : WidgetUi KERN-EXEC 3"

Tags: ajax, cordova, symbian, nokia-wrt, jquery-1.8

I develop phonegap app for symbian (cordova for symbian I'm get from [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-symbian.wrt/tree/a779600377f17511f2ff94beb0ab9e8a357860e1))

After 3-5 seconds when my app begin execute `ajax` request, I get error:

[image]

Maybe someone faced with this issue?

---

Update1:

I make cross-domain ajax request with `jquery mobile 1.8.1`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://example.org/some/path",
    dataType: "json",
    mimeType: "application/json",
    headers: { "TOKEN": "%SOME_TOKEN%" }

 }).done(function (data) {
     // success processing
 }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus) {
     // fail processing
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be as simple as the fact that you're missing `"` from the `url` line of your AJAX creation, but I suspect it isn't. I'm guessing that's a copying typo. This error message means your getting an uncaught exception which is bringing your app down.

Other people have reported JQuery for mobile being buggy, and having problems with certain HTTP Response statuses. I suggest bypassing it altogether, and making your own AJAX request, as a workaround (plenty of examples on the internet; I would `alert` the response status just so you can see what you're getting).. If that works, you can investigate whether other version of JQuery suffer from the same bugs.

Example AJAX without JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
  {
    // do stuff with xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

Comment: `you're missing " from the url` it is just misprint. Is emulator has any `event log`?

Comment: Can you provide me link to `ajax` complete example that will correctly work on Symbian?

Answer (score 1):

KERN-EXEC 3 is due to referencing a bad pointer or running out of stack space. It's probably the latter but it's impossible to say. Is there any way you can provide a call-stack?

Comment: Looks like no, because this issue doesn't repro on `Nokia Web App simulator` only on `epoc` emulator